# VBscript out in Jenkins console

Tags: vbscript, jenkins

I have a vbscript which will be invoked from command window. The code will be deployed in Jenkins soon. I want to know how to monitor the code running in Jenkins console

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before running your script run the following command from command line,

The default scripting engine for Windows 2000 and onwards is WScript. To change the default scripting engine from WScript to CScript, type the following line:

```
 cscript //h:cscript //s
```

here is a link for more info:
[HERE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245254)

this should help you see the result on the console window.